# How to detect if a player out of one team dies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've got a vanilla server for 1.10 and I already did a scoreboard with two different Teams (`red`, `blue`). Now I want to check if either a player on team red or a player on team blue dies and to have a redstone output out of it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You may  want to take a look into creating an objective with the "teamkill" criterion and then use "/scoreboard players test @a <objective> 1" to determine a kill of a member of the team. Instantly afterwards resetting with "/scoreboard players set @a <objective> 0". Do this for both teams.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an objective to keep track of deaths:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
```

To test if a a player on red team had died, run this command:

```
/testfor @a[team=red,score_Deaths_min=1]
```

To test if a player on blue team had died, run this command:

```
/testfor @a[team=blue,score_Deaths_min=1]
```

You'll then probably need to set their `Deaths` back to 0 after doing what you want to do:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Deaths_min=1] Deaths 0
```